# Poner el elemento que yo quiera de una lista en el spinner Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Lo que estoy intentando es que un usuario seleccione un elemento a través de un spinner, yo guardo ese elemento a través de la position y lo que quiero es que cuando el usuario vuelva para editar spinner se le muestre el que marco primeramente.

Os dejo aqui parte del codigo, declaraciones:

```
private Spinner spinnerSeason;

private int season = 0;

private String[] Seasons = new String[] {
            "Estacion",
            "Indiferente",
            "Invierno",
            "Primavera",
            "Verano",
            "Otoño"
    };
```

Esto entraria dentro del onCreate del activity:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapterSeason  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Seasons);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        spinnerArrayAdapterSeason.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinnerSeason.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapterSeason);
        spinnerSeason.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (parent.getId()) {
                    case R.id.spinnerSeason:
                        //tv.setText(tv.getText() + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                        season = position;
                        break;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                //Another interface callback
            }
        });
```

Inicializamos el spinner:

```
    spinnerSeason = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSeason);
```

Aquí sería donde debería de cargar el elemento del spinner que el usuario marco anteriormente. A partir de un método, le digo que se ejecute si el usuario esta editando, pero no carga el que el usuario marco sino el primero del vector.

```
    spinnerSeason.setVerticalScrollbarPosition(season);
```

season tiene el valor que marco el usuario anteriormente. falla el método de la clase Spinner.

Answer (score 1):

usa array `SharedPreferences`:

```
   spinnerSeason.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapterSeason);
    //para obtener la posicion del spinner desde SharedPreferences:
    final SharedPreferences[] sharedPref = {getActivity().getSharedPreferences("SpinnerEj", MODE_PRIVATE)};
    int spinnerValor = sharedPref[0].getInt("itemSeleccionado",-1);
    if(spinnerValor != -1) {
        // configuras el valor del spinner guardado
        spinnerSeason.setSelection(spinnerValor);
    }

    spinnerSeason.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // aquí obtienes el valor del spinner (int position)y lo guardas dentro de SharedPreferences:
            int valorSeleccionado = spinnerSeason.getSelectedItemPosition();
            sharedPref[0] = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("SpinnerEj",0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref[0].edit();
            prefEditor.putInt("itemSeleccionado",valorSeleccionado);
            prefEditor.commit();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Otra opción sería usar `onSaveInstanceState`, pero en este caso si la app se cierra los valores no se guardan.

Ejemplo si lo quieres guardar en una base de datos, en este caso SQLite con Content Provider, para verlo en un ListView/RecyclerView.

Y suponiendo que el array lo tienes en recursos como: `R.array.seasons`.

Para guardar la posición del item del spinner, en tu SQLite la columna debe ser de tipo INTEGER

```
TuTabla.TU_COLUMNA + " INTEGER, " + ...
```

Obtienes un `int` de la posición a guardar:

```
int itemSeleccionado = spinnerSeason.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Lo guardas en tu base de datos así:

```
contentValues.put(TuTabla.TU_COLUMNA, itemSeleccionado);
```

En el ViewHolder tienes que agregar el ArrayAdapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerArrayAdapterSeason = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(v.getContext(), R.array.seasons, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
spinnerSeason.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapterSeason);
```

En tu adapter hay que hacer referencia al array:

```
int[] numSeleccionado = holder.itemView.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.seasons);
```

Y así lo agregas a tu vista:

```
holder.spinnerSeason.setSelection(numSeleccionado);
```

Comment: Buenas, solo comentarte que tu codigo funciona muy bien. Pero me gustaría que me explicaras que es lo que hace exactamente. Saludos

Comment: No me entendiste bien, en mi programa tengo un listView con muchos articulos. Con tu sugerencia comparto el valor del spinner en los demas. Yo lo que quiero es guardar lo que marca el usuario y cuando vuelva a entrar en ese articulo se ponga la seleccionada anteriormente y si entra en otro la que marque. Siendo las selecciones diferentes.

Comment: estas usando SQLite?

Comment: Estoy usando Realm

Comment: estas guardando la position del spinner a Realm, si? lo que quieres es que se muestre esa position guardada en el ListView?

Comment: Si, guardo la position. Pero no soy capaz de mostrarla

Comment: No tengo experiencia con Realm, pero te dejo un ejemplo de como sería con SQLite/Content Provider